# Firestore pricing on duplicate listeners

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

If I create multiple `onSnapshot` listeners for the same document in different places in my code, will I be charged once (one document) or multiple times (for each listener).

Does it make sense to write a wrapper around Firestore that does this or is this built-in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing#listens):

> Cloud Firestore allows you to listen to the results of a query and get
>   realtime updates when the query results change.
>
> When you listen to the results of a query, you are charged for a read
>   each time a document in the result set is added or updated. You are
>   also charged for a read when a document is removed from the result set
>   because the document has changed. (In contrast, when a document is
>   deleted, you are not charged for a read.)
>
> Also, if the listener is disconnected for more than 30 minutes (for
>   example, if the user goes offline), you will be charged for reads as
>   if you had issued a brand-new query.

What you decide to do afterwards will heavily depend on your use case and your application needs.

Comment: Yes, I know that. The question was much rather if the library itself is optimized in that regard or if calling onSnapshot twice will result in two reads. I'd imagine it is since it would be stupid otherwise, but I couldn't find any clear answers for this so far.

Comment: Hi @CiriousJoker, thanks for explaining further. If I understood your question correctly, you will only be charged once per document read operation - you will just have `x` observables listening in for the same document reference for any changes, as per the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/query-data/listen). So you will make one call to the server and be charged for one read operation just one time; however, if changes in your document came into play, you will definitely be charged for these.

Comment: Can you clarify? 2 listeners for the same document in the same app results in 1 "actual" listener, right? 2 listeners for the same document across different apps results in 2 "actual" listeners, right? So whenever the document changes, I get charged based on "actual" listeners? Also, what's your source?

Comment: I guess, if the listeners are in the same app, there should be only one charge. But that depends on the implementation, which should take this into consideration and only charge once. I have been looking at some "listen" [Node.js Firestore client](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-firestore/blob/ce89a3017168ea9bd16a361dde5a5370feb1df45/dev/src/v1/firestore_client.ts#L1019) code; you might find something interesting [here](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/search?q=listen&unscoped_q=listen).

Comment: I am also curious as to what the behavior will be for firestore webSDK v9.
This is not only important for billing, but also app performance.